# How to emit a token in ANTLR4?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

This is my `grammar.g4`:

```
FOO: 'x';
BAR: 'y'
  { /* here! */ };
```

I want tokens `BAR` and `FOO` to be emitted when the input contains `y`. What should I write in the `here!` part? Please, don't suggest to rewrite the grammar, this is just a test sample, my real case is much more complex.

Comment: When questions are too much simplified, I often end up answering an X-Y problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Could you explain your real case and provide real examples?

Comment: @BartKiers see how tokens are emitted at the `NEWLINE` rule [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python/python3/Python3.g4). I need a similar mechanism, but in a very basic form.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it. I even wrote that code you linked to ;). I just wanted to see a real life use case from your actual grammar.

Comment: @BartKiers it's a small world :) Can you give me an example for the code above please? Using it I will be able to do the same in my own code (and many other users too!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick demo:

```
grammar T;

@lexer::members {
  private java.util.LinkedList<Token> tokens = new java.util.LinkedList<>();

  @Override
  public Token nextToken() {
    return tokens.isEmpty() ? super.nextToken() : tokens.poll();
  }
}

parse
 : foo bar foo EOF
 ;

foo : FOO;
bar : BAR;

FOO : 'x';
BAR : 'y' {this.tokens.offer(new CommonToken(TLexer.FOO, "x"));};

SPACES : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Test with:

```java
TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString("x y"));
TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

System.out.println(parser.parse().toStringTree(parser));
```

which will print:

```
(parse (foo x) (bar y) (foo x) <EOF>)
```